# How to use Facebook social plug-in on Google sites?

Tags: facebook, facebook-social-plugins, google-sites

I'm trying any forms, but no succes. Anyone do that in your google site?

In this [tutorial](http://gadgets.joinrsite.com/get/facebook-like-button) i can put the comments box on site but don't works.

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use facebook plugings on Google sites , 
you must go here : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/

You have many plugins.

if you want to put a commentBox,
go here : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/comments

In the Url : take your url of your Google Sites, take the iframe Code, And copy this Code on your Google sites ( in your page html ).